# Renaming a pdf file (scanned document) using OCR. It should read 3 zones and rename accordingly. e.g. Streetname_LastName_Date.pdf

Tags: pdf, rename, ocr, batch-rename

I am running into trouble with tons of paperwork. I want to have it digitalized in order to simplify search and therefore cut down a huge amount of time spent on looking though the paperwork.

It is rather simple, I want to scan documents, which share the same layout and rename it according to 3 areas within the document. In my case its a reference number, a Last name and the date listed on the document. It would be even better if it could move the files to folders named after an area in the document.

Here is an image, basically this but with hundreds of pdfs in batch.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yKaW.png

I couldn't find any solution for days and yet the technology is there. Have you ever gotten across a problem like this and found a solution? I would really appreciate your help.

The closes thing I have found is a program called FileCenter, but you need to click a button for each scan. Using ocr on existing files require you to go through a 3 click menu for each file. I wonder if there is an easy batch program, where you just select the rectangles and it does the renaming part.

I will edit this OP if any solution can be found, for anyone googling.

Answer (score 0):

You may do this with the commercial component [ByteScout PDF Extractor SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) designed specifically for this purpose. It may extract text from a given region by coordinates with optional OCR (that also works in the selected extraction region) in a batch. Coordinates of the region to extract text from can be measured in the base document with [PDF Multitool](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html) free utility (asssuming all your PDF files are using the same layout).

You may extract text from given regions in C# like using OCR (English language):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Bytescout.PDFExtractor;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
    // Create Bytescout.PDFExtractor.TextExtractor instance
    TextExtractor extractor = new TextExtractor();
    extractor.RegistrationName = "demo";
    extractor.RegistrationKey = "demo";
    // enable OCR auto mode, will use English by default
    extractor.OCRMode = OCRMode.Auto; 

    string sourceFile = "sample.pdf";

    // Load source PDF file
    extractor.LoadDocumentFromFile(sourceFile);

    // extract from given area (measured from base typical file using PDF Multitool utility), assuming we have a reference string there

    extractor.SetExtractionArea(Rectangle.FromLTRB(10, 10, 100,100));
    string extractedReference = extractor.GetTextFromPage(0).Trim();
    extractor = null; // dispose the extractor and release the original file

    // Copy the original file into the file with filename based on the original reference so it will be like "1234-sample.pdf" 
    string outputFile =  extractedReference + "-" + sourceFile;
    File.Copy(sourceFile, outputFile);

    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(inputFile + " has been copied to " + outputFile);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
    Console.ReadKey();

  }
 }
}
```

*Disclosure: I'm connected with ByteScout*